# Can xref-find-definitions jump into packages in venv?

Tags: xref

I have following Python file and my cursor is on top of `os`, or `sys`, or `pprint`. When I do `xref-find-definitions` it does not jump into their definition that is I belive location on the `~/venv` file. Is it possible to accomplish it using `xref`?

Please note that it can jump into functions that are defined in my repo.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os
import sys
from pprint import pprint
from my_function import my_function  # it can jump into my_function
```

Comment: Doesn't `xref` use `etags` for finding things? If so, using the `etags` program from the command line, you can produce a TAGS file that indexes whatever directories you want.

Comment: How can I produce a TAGS file not sure how?

Comment: Do `man etags`: it's a CLI program to do that.

Comment: I am coding Python/shell within emacs and I am 100% dependable to emacs. I just want to be able to jump into a module definitions and come back. I have tried `elpy`, which used to work but not any more on my setup. I even re-installed ubuntu but no help. `jedi` also used to work but it just stop working keep saying definition is not found. I am out of bullets, lately I tried, `rope` which works but now it does not jump back. // https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/63791/18414 .

Comment: `xref` is basically a frontend to a number of systems. So the actual behavior, where it can jump or cannot, depends on the current backend. Core Emacs ships with two backends: one for Elisp and another for everything else: etags. Being able to use the latter one depends on you building a TAGS file and updaing it regularly.

Among popular 3rd party backends are `lsp-mode`, `dumb-jump` and https://github.com/pythonic-emacs/anaconda-mode.